# Custom NavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, eureka-forms

I've started to use Eureka in my project. Eureka don't working with custom navigation controller. And in the ViewControllers where I use Eureka I need to use native navigation controller. Code for open ViewController:

```
    let vc = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerWithEurekaForm") as! ViewControllerWithEurekaForm
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But,  when I click back to the previous ViewController, code:

```
    let controller : ViewControllerWithCustomNavigation = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerWithCustomNavigation") as! ViewControllerWithCustomNavigation
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: false)
```

I also have navigationController from rootViewController (previous controller with Eureka). How can I go back ViewController (ViewControllerWithCustomNavigation) and have custom navigation controller?

Comment: use dismissviewcontroller if you present

Comment: If I use dismissviewcontroller I can't to close the previous controller on a new one (ViewControllerWithCustomNavigation). But I need to download again ViewControllerWithCustomNavigation when ViewControllerWithEurekaForm was close.

Comment: But I could use NSNotificationCenter. Is there other way?

Comment: delegates one of the good way

Comment: What do you mean?